# how to forward variable number of arguments to another function?

Tags: c++

In my application I have a lot of logs. I do accumulate all errors from all logs in one place called `errorsLogger`. I've implemented it this way:

```
static Logger errorsLogger;

....

void Logger::Error(std::string format, ...) {
    va_list arglist;
    va_start(arglist, format);

    if (this != &errorsLogger) {
        errorsLogger.Error(format, arglist);      // how to forward parameters?
    }

    vfprintf(logFile, , format.c_str(), arglist);
    fprintf(logFile, "\n");

    fflush(logFile);
    va_end( arglist );
}
```

However this code doesn't work as expected `errorsLogger` contains a little bit strange strings - it seems variable arguments was not passed. How to fix my code to be valid?

Comment: You need a version of `Error` that takes a [`va_list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variadic/va_list).

Comment: Consider changing interface of your logger so it's looking like `ostream`, you will be able to do things like: `Logger::error() << "the variable x is " << x;` In fact `Logger::error()` can return an `ostream&`

Comment: can I just format a string as a first step and then just forward std::string?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The typical formulation of this in C is to have two functions, one that accepts `...` and one that accepts a `va_list` (e.g., `printf` versus `vprintf`). In C++ it’s convenient to do this with overloads:

```
// public
void Logger::Error(const std::string& format, ...) {
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, format);
    Error(format, args);
    va_end(args);
}

// private
void Logger::Error(const std::string& format, va_list args) {
    if (this != &errorsLogger)
        errorsLogger.Error(format, args);

    vfprintf(logFile, format.c_str(), args);
    fprintf(logFile, "\n");
    fflush(logFile);
}
```

Using C++11, it is possible to do directly with a variadic template. You can also forward arguments to C-style variadic functions.

```
template<class... Args>
void Logger::Error(const std::string& format, Args&&... args) {    
    if (this != &errorsLogger)
        errorsLogger.Error(format, std::forward<Args>(args)...);

    fprintf(logFile, format.c_str(), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    fprintf(logFile, "\n");
    fflush(logFile);
}
```

Comment: You can definitely use variadic templates to forward to C variadic functions.

Answer (score 5):

In short, you can't.

All you can do is write an equivalent member function that takes a `va_list` instead of variable arguments, and pass the initialized `va_list` down.

Comment: Why are you downvoting this?

Comment: Maybe someone wanted it to be shorter? Or they're an organic chemist that prefers to write OC(OH)₂? Hard to say, really.

Comment: @CodyGray LOL, good point about organic chemists.

Answer (score 0):

For that to work, `Logger::Error` would have to be declared to accept a `va_list` as a parameter, much like vfprintf, rather than variable arguments in the form of  `...` like fprintf.